# New line ine create file

Tags: php, file

When I try to create a file I can't make new line/carriage return.
Why is it not working? I tried with :

- `PHP_EOL`
- `\n`

But it is not creating new lines when I look it with notepad

```
<?php

$file = 'myText.txt';

$id = '1'.$file;
//explode($delimiter, $id);

$content = "<PMTags1.0 win>". PHP_EOL;
$content .= . PHP_EOL;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $content .= "<@win:><\<>win>". $row['kategoria'] . PHP_EOL;
  $content .= "<@tekst:><\<>tekst><$>";
  $content .= $row['text'];
  $content .= $gcid.$row['id'].'/'. PHP_EOL;
}

utf8_encode($content);
echo $content;
//Stworzenie pliku
$fp = fopen(trim(trim($id)),"wb");

fwrite($fp,$content);
fwrite($fp, pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf));
fopen(trim(trim($id)),"r");
fclose($fp);
//End 4
//5 - Otwarcie pliku



if (file_exists(trim($id))) {
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename(trim($id)));
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize(trim($id)));
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  readfile(trim($id));
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Notepad does not show `\n` to you, it's an invisible instruction.

Comment: Try Notepad++. It's much better.

Comment: If you're creating the file on a server that uses *nix line endings ("\n"), but displaying in Windows notepad that requires windows line endings ("\r\n") then it will all seem as though it's one line - either open the file in Notepad++ or an editor that can read files with *nix line endings, or use "\r\n"

Comment: If i use notpad++ evryfing is good but if i use notpad windows is wrong.

BTW I have problem with utf-8...

Answer (score 1):

For Linux systems the new line character is `\n`

For Mac systems `\r` is enough (Thanks SIT_LCU).

For Windows you must add `\r` next to `\n`

Comment: actually, some Mac systems rely on `\r` only. reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crlf#Representations

Answer (score 1):

Simply said,

```
\r\n
```

is your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use PHP_EOL for the output of a textfile, you can better use:

```
\n\r
```

For better compatibility

Answer (score 0):

`PHP_EOL` is "The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform."

But probably you are creating the file on Unix and look at it under Windows - where the `EOL`-symbol is different.

Comment: As the others suggested, a good editor will help.  [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) (my favourite) will be suiteable...

Answer (score 0):

\n = CR (Carriage Return) // Used as a new line character in Unix
\r = LF (Line Feed) // Used as a new line character in Mac OS
\r\n = CR + LF // Used as a new line character in Windows
[NewLine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

\n is correctly represented in some browsers and tools,
but to get the proper results for all users it is best to use "\r\n" for new line.